# keep fancybox bindings preventing parent jquery action

Tags: jquery

Okay, quickly.
I've this DIV loaded by $.ajax() and has the following jquery live() attached to `$('div').live('click', function(event) {});` but inside this DIV there is an anchor for a jquery fancybox gallery.

html:

```
<div>
    <a class="foo" href="some-image.png"><img src="some-thumb.png"></a>
    <a class="foo" href="some-image2.png"><img src="some-thumb2.png"></a>
    <a class="foo" href="some-image2.png"><img src="some-thumb2.png"></a>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('div').live('click', function(event) {
     alert();
});
$('.foo').fancybox();
```

I want to prevent the div action from executing after i click on the gallery link...
Im stucked a bit on this. 
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), take a look to my example http://jsfiddle.net/abimaelmartell/ZS8Yw/

```
$('a').on("click",function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("link");
})
```